# One column table in two columns article

Tags: tables, two-column, columnbreak

I've found similar posts in the forum, but none is specifically correct for my problem.

I'm writing a two columns article (`\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{article}`) and I need to break the two columns template for insert a big table. I only want a new page with only the table. Is this possibile? Thanks.